# Generate uuid and then insert data from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have 2 tables in Postgres

| main | entity |
| --- | --- |
| id | id |
| name | name |
|  | main_id |

I need to generate id for entity, get name and id from main and insert into entity table

```
INSERT INTO entity (select uuid_generate_v4(), name, main_id)
SELECT name, id FROM main
```

But I get this error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
```

I know that the point is that I am inserting more arguments than I receive, but I do not know how to proceed further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first pair of parentheses define the target *columns* of the INSERT statement. You need to move the UUID generation to the SELECT part:

```
INSERT INTO entity (id, name, main_id)
SELECT uuid_generate_v4(), name, id 
FROM main
```

Comment: Thank you!
And if after that I need to get the generated id of these entities and insert it into the main table, for example, as entity_id

Comment: Why would you need that? The `entity` table already contains a reference to the main table.